# Aurelia.js change button color or class after click

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Aurelia.js Changing button color or class after click.

How can do this with Aurelia? change from primary to danger after click on this button?

thank you.

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a class binding and a click binding.

Bindings:
http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics

Basic example:

```
//view.html
<button type="button" class="btn ${clicked ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-primary'}" click.trigger="handleClick()">Click</button>

//view.js
...
  clicked = false;

  handleClick(){
    this.clicked = !this.clicked; // toggle clicked true/false
    return true; // only needed if you want to cancel preventDefault()
  }
```

If you want, you can get a similar result by binding the style directly.